# $f$ is a continuous function satisfying $d(x, y)\leq d(f(x), f(y))$ Then $f(X) = X$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

Suppose that $(X, d)$ is a compact metric space and that $f : X \to X$ is a continuous function satisfying $d(x, y)\leq d(f(x), f(y))$ for all $x, y \in X$. Then $f(X) = X$.

I tried to do this as the following but my professor told me that it is not working, because of the following;

Suppose by contradiction that $f(X)\neq X$ and $d(x, y)\leq d(f(x), f(y))$  is satisfied. Also since, $f$ is continuous on a compact set is takes its maximum.
So $\exists a \in X$ s.t. $d(x,f(x)) \leq d(a,f(a)) \forall x\in X$.

(but he said that $f(a)$ be maximum does not mean that  $d(a,f(a)) $ is the maximum) I did not understand his point.

then let $a=x$ and $y=f(a)$, using the property we'd have $d(a,f(a)) \leq d(f(a),f(f(a))) $. So if $f(x) \neq x$, this is a contradiction.

I also have another proof which he gave, but cannot understand it. Is there any alternative proof doing it by contradiction ?

Comment: Take $X = [0,1]$ and consider the function $f(x) = x$. Sure, $x=1$ is where the maximum occurs but $d(1,f(1)) = 0$.

Comment: @NinadMunshi But that *is* the maximum of $x\mapsto |x-x|$. However, it's correct that OP has only managed to prove that $a$ maximising $d(x,f(x)),$ just must have $d(f(a),f(f(a))=d(a,f(a))$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Good point! Let's take $f(x)=x^2$ instead so that $d(1,f(1))$ is not the maximum anymore.

Comment: What does the 'maximum of $f$' even mean when $X$ does not have an ordering? For instance, what if $X=[0,1]^2$ is the unit square?

Comment: Also, suppose that $a\in X$ is chosen so that $d(x,f(x))\leq d(a,f(a))$ holds for all $x\in X$ (which is possible by the Extreme Value Theorem since $x\mapsto d(x,f(x))$ is a continuous map from the compact set $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$). Then why is the inequality $$d(a,f(a))\leq d(f(a),f(f(a)))$$ a contradiction? For instance, if $X=S^1$ is the unit circle and $f(x)$ is the rotation by $90^{\circ}$, then we in fact have $d(x,y)=d(f(x),f(y))$ for all $x,y\in S^1$ while both the assumption and the conclusion holds for this $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. Here's a somewhat simple proof of the fact:

Assume for contradiction $y\in X\setminus f(X)$. In particular, since $f(X)$ is compact, there exists some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B(y,\varepsilon)\cap f(X)=\emptyset$. In particular, $d(y,f(y))\geq \varepsilon$. However, applying the property of $f$, we have $d(f(y),f(f(X))\geq \varepsilon$, and in particular $d(f(y),f(f(y))\geq \varepsilon.$

Proceeding by induction, let $f^{\circ n}$ denote the $n$'th composition of $f$ with itself and note that the sequence $(f^{\circ n}(y))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ satisfies that $d(f^{\circ n}(y),f^{\circ k}(y))\geq \varepsilon$ whenever $n\neq k$. Thus, this sequence cannot have a subsequence which is Cauchy, and in particular, it cannot have a convergent subsequence. This contradicts compactness of $X$, and we conclude that $y\in f(X)$